# How to create anonymous IDispatch functions with ATL?

Tags: winapi, com, atl, idispatch, atlcom

Is there an easy way to create a class that is derived from IDispatch and that can be passed to API like this (this is C++ ):

```
pDOM2->attachEvent(CComBSTR("event"), new DispatchFunction);
```

I know how to create a C++ object that handle an invoke with a dispid of value 0 but it's always a bit painful to implement all IDispatch by hand. I was wondering if ATL has some standard way of doing it as it is fairly common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default ATL creates "auto-dual" COM classes.  They support both early binding *and* IDispatch.  You'll see IDispatchImpl<> in their inheritance list.  You declare the dispid in the IDL.  No extra work is required.

Comment: You're right, I always wondered if there was support and actually I knew all I needed without seeing it. Thanks.